# Get str_replace to avoid replacing selected tags

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code below which find any less than and greater than HTML Character Entities in the users question and replaces them with suitable entity name

```
$string = $this->input->post('question');

$find_and_replace = array(
    '<' => '&lt;',
    '>' => '&gt;',
);

$new_data = str_replace(array_keys($find_and_replace), array_values($find_and_replace), $string);
```

When there are tags like `<pre></pre>` and `<code></code>` in the question

it replaces them as well `&lt;pre&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;` and `&lt;code&gt;&lt;/code&gt;`

**I do not want that to happen only to replace the** content inside the tags.

> **Question** How can I still use the str_replace but only the content
>   inside pre tag or code tag.

```
public function preview() {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'question' => '', 'tag' => '');

    if ($_POST) {

        $string = $this->input->post('question');

        $find_and_replace = array(
            '<' => '&lt;',
            '>' => '&gt;',
        );

        $new_data = str_replace(array_keys($find_and_replace), array_values($find_and_replace), $string);

        $data['question'] = $new_data;

        $data['success'] = true;
    }

    $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($data));
}

function get_everything_in_tags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove pre tag I just want it to avoid having `<` and `>` replaced around pre tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this:

```
$new_data = preg_replace_callback("#</?(pre|code)>|[<>]#", function ($match) {
    return $match[0] == '<' ? '&lt;' : ($match[0] == '>' ? '&gt;' : $match[0]);
}, $string);
```

It will preserve the `<pre>` and `<code>` opening and closing tags and only replace the other `<` and `>` characters.

Note that in general replacement methods are not the ideal way to work with HTML. You could look into [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php) to parse HTML and get the text content of the elements in an HTML string.

Answer (score 1):

```
strip_tags($input, '<pre>');
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/5j9)**

> **Updated** Replace `<` and `>` outside `<pre></pre>` and `<code></code>` block.

```
$pattern = array(
    "(<(pre|code)(?:\s+\w+(?:=\w+|\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+')?)*>.*?</(pre|code)>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)"
    ."|<)is",
    "(<(pre|code)(?:\s+\w+(?:=\w+|\"[^\"]+\"|'[^']+')?)*>.*?</(pre|code)>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)"
    ."|>)is",
);
$replacement = array("&lt;", "&gt", "&lt;", "&gt");
$out = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
echo htmlspecialchars($out);
```

http://phpio.net/s/60t

Comment: Where abouts would be suited in function ?

Comment: Because I dont want to remove pre tag I just want it to avoid having `<` and `>` replaced around pre tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you'll be parsing large text strings, it'll be most efficient to use a function from the MB (megabyte-length strings) package.  For example...

```
$input = "<b>Hello!</b>";
$conversion_bit_mask = [
    0x003c, 0x003c, 0, 0xffff, // < sign
    0x003e, 0x003e, 0, 0xffff, // > sign
];
$input_cleansed = mb_encode_numericentity($input, $conversion_bit_mask, $format);
print($input_cleansed); // output is: &gt;b&lt;Hello!&gt;/b&lt;
```